# <cstdint> vs std::size_t types

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

From the peeks I've made into `boost` and `libstdc++`, the libraries usually make use of `std::size_t` and `std::ssize_t` whenever the upper/lower limit of an unsigned/signed index is not known in advance. My question is: Why not rather use `uintmax_t` from `<cstdint>` instead of `std::size_t` and `intmax_t` instead of `std::ssize_t`?

Comment: I don't think `std::ssize_t` exists. POSIX defines `ssize_t`, but it's not part of the C++ standard. C++ uses `std::size_t` and `std::ptrdiff_t`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I think I tried to use `std::ssize_t` once and it worked. Of course this is compiler-specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++11 standard (section 18.2) says:

> (5). The type `ptrdiff_t` is an implementation-deﬁned signed integer type that can hold the diﬀerence of two subscripts in an array object....
>
> (6). The type `size_t` is an implementation-deﬁned unsigned integer type that is large enough to contain the size in bytes of any object.
>
> (7). [*Note:* It is recommended that implementations choose types for `ptrdiff_t` and `size_t` whose integer conversion ranks (4.13) are no greater than that of `signed long int` unless a larger size is necessary to contain all the possible values. *—end note*]

From this we see that:

`size_t` is specifically for byte-sizes of objects, and its companion `ptrdiff_t` is specifically for math with array indices.  `uintmax_t`, on the other hand, is the largest unsigned integral type.

Depending on the platform `uintmax_t` could be larger than `size_t`.

We also know that:

`sizeof` returns a `size_t`, and the STL container `size_type`s are typically identical to `size_t`, so it makes sense to use `size_t` in code that deals with `sizeof` or STL containers.

Now mix in the fact the `<cstdint>` is new-ish to C++, and I think it's pretty clear why established libraries like Boost have been using `size_t`.

Comment: But if `uintmax_t` is larger than `size_t`, then it can contain the size of an even larger object, than `size_t` can.

Comment: Also, `boost` implements it's own `<cstdint>`, as `cstdint.hpp`, check it out http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/cstdint.hpp

Comment: @user1095108 The standard says that `size_t` can contain the size of the largest possible type. So if a value doesn't fit into `size_t`, it isn't the size of an object.

Answer (score 3):

The former are part of the C++ standard, the latter are not. More precisely, the `cstdint` header was only recently introduced (in C++11). The reason for this is that `stdint.h` itself is part of C99, which is newer than C++98.

Comment: Also, `size_t` is more descriptive and can be appropriately smaller than `uintmax_t`.

Comment: You seem to forget that `size_t` is a part of the `C` standard as well, but `C` libraries also prefer using `size_t` to `uintmax_t`.

Comment: As I said stdint.h is C99, and you can use the same C lib also to compile C89.

Answer (score 2):

Because the size_t types are intended to describe the sizes of things. Using them for sizes is more descriptive than uint_t.

Also, it might be possible for an architecture to be limited to smaller sizes of things so size_t might not always be the biggest integer type. Although I think that would be a bit weird.

Comment: `size_t` not being the biggest integer type is common whenever the platform bitness is smaller than 64Bit, or if there are extended range integers.

Comment: In particular, `size_t` not being the biggest integer type is the norm on x86.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Should I have said biggest natural integer type? I know the compiler can synthesize 64 bit operations on 32-bit systems but the actual machine instructions are 32 bit.

Comment: In a question involving `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t`, "biggest integer type" pretty clearly doesn't mean biggest "natural" integer type, no matter that "natural" means, but even then: I haven't used x32 recently, but I seem to recall that `size_t` is still 32 bits even though 64-bit registers and instructions are available.

Comment: @hvd is `sizeof(size_t)` ever < `sizeof(uintmax_t)`. Can you give example, where this is the case?

Comment: and whats descriptive or not is also a bit dependent on the taste/background of an individual. `uintmax_t` may be more descriptive, say, to a mathematician.

Comment: @user1095108 I already gave two examples in my earlier comments.